# How to do permutation of characters and print it horizontally along that row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-custom-function

I am stuck here in printing permutation of two or more characters horizontally along that row in which the characters are. 
Is it possible? Because I searched it all over and only found vertical output along the column.

I have to make permutations of different people from different community and create their user names. The below is what I get after entering my formula

[image]

Here is the code:

```
function permuteEmails(a,b,c) {
  var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName('Person Details');
  var array = [];

  var aVal = sheet.getRange(a).getDisplayValue();
  var bVal = sheet.getRange(b).getDisplayValue();
  var cVal = sheet.getRange(c).getDisplayValue();

  var aVal_first = aVal.slice(0,1);
  var bVal_first = bVal.slice(0,1);

  array.push(aVal + "." + bVal + "@" + cVal);
  array.push(bVal + "." + aVal + "@" + cVal);
  array.push(aVal + "@" + cVal);
  array.push(aVal + "." + bVal_first + "@" + cVal);
  array.push(aVal + bVal_first + "@" + cVal);
  array.push(aVal_first + bVal + "@" + cVal);

  return array;
}
```

But I want it to look like, that after entering the details and applying the formula, all the combinations should print along the same row in which we entered the details.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I have made the changes

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? or add the permuteemails script you use?

Comment: I have added the code. Please look into it.

Comment: Yes, It works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I have to enter 1000+ entry, the script doesn't work on copying the formula and pasting in different blocks. Can you suggest something about this.

Comment: did you try the arrayformula from my answer? its way much better than the script

Comment: The formula works great but what about 1000+ entries? If I have to create such permutations on a large number, do I have to write formula each time for respective entry? because this formula is not working when it is copied.

Comment: arrayformula does not need to be copied over rows. its auto-completing whole range from the first row. it will work even on 3000+ entries. (see the 2nd image). can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I didn't try the second formula. This is working perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try: **`=TRANSPOSE(PERMUTEEMAILS("A2", "B2", "C2"))`**

  [image: 0]
- or use this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), LOWER({
   A2:A&"."&B2:B&"@"&C2:C, 
   B2:B&"."&A2:A&"@"&C2:C,
   B2:B&"@"&C2:C,
   B2:B&"."&LEFT(A2:A, 1)&"@"&C2:C,
   B2:B&LEFT(A2:A, 1)&"@"&C2:C,
   LEFT(B2:B, 1)&A2:A&"@"&C2:C}), ))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: @HimanshuSharma answer updated